# is the email content returned from gmail api as safe from attacks as the gmail browser client app?

Tags: javascript, email, security, gmail-api

I'm creating my own browser-based email client, and am concerned about the security of the email body content returned from Google GMail API.

I understand Google does a range of cleansing to prevent CSS attacks etc. Is this all done server-side of their API calls before returning the content to me? Is it true to say what they return in their APIs are as safe as their client application? Do I need to perform any additional checks?

Comment: You mean *XSS* attacks, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant XSS (cross-site scripting) not CSS (cascading style sheets), and any other similar security vulnerabilities.